# Movie List By Category (Java)

Tags: java, syntax

I am a total noob to this Java thing and my introduction to programming was last year and I Loved it but I am still trying to understand it. I have been to this site before with my problems from learning Ruby on Rails. Awesome site!

Well onto my issue... I m taking a class and I am trying to find out what might be causing this issue.  Not asking for someone to do the work for me...I just want to know why it is happening. I am stumped.

Everything seems to work fine until I enter the "drama category ..where it also spits out the horror movie category as well. I originally set it up for if/else but then net-beans convinced me to use the switch method. if I didn't it wouldn't compile.Any advice on maybe using another method/statement?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MovieList {


    public static void main(String[] args)  

    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Movie List Application");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("There are 100 movie in the list");
        String choice = "y";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> animated = new ArrayList<>();
         animated.add("Robot Chicken");
         animated.add("Family Guy");
         animated.add("American Dad");
         animated.add("Bob's Burgers");
         animated.add("The Simpsons");


         ArrayList<String>drama = new ArrayList<>();
         drama.add("John Q");
         drama.add("The Green Mile");
         drama.add("The Breakfast Club");
         drama.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
         drama.add("Braveheart");

         ArrayList<String> horror = new ArrayList<>();
         drama.add("Scream");
         drama.add("Carrie");
         drama.add("Insideous");
         drama.add("Insideous");
         drama.add("Sinister");

         ArrayList<String> scifi = new ArrayList<>();
         scifi.add("The Book of Eli");
         scifi.add("Daybreakers");
         scifi.add("Hunter Prey");
         scifi.add("Predators");
         scifi.add("Skyline");

        while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            {
            System.out.print("What category are you interested in?");

                        String movielist = sc.nextLine();
                    switch (movielist) {
                        case "animated":
                            System.out.println(animated);
                            break;
                        case "drama":
                            System.out.println(drama);
                            break;
                        case "horror":
                            System.out.println(horror);
                            break;
                        case "scifi":
                            System.out.println(scifi);
                            break;
                    }

            System.out.print("Continue? y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            }
                    }


    }
```

Comment: The lines under `horror` all begin with `drama.add(...` so I think it's just a typo there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are adding your horror films in the drama array list. Change this:

```
ArrayList<String> horror = new ArrayList<>();
         drama.add("Scream");
         drama.add("Carrie");
         drama.add("Insideous");
         drama.add("Insideous");
         drama.add("Sinister");
```

To this:

```
   ArrayList<String> horror = new ArrayList<>();
     horror.add("Scream");
     horror.add("Carrie");
     horror.add("Insideous");
     horror.add("Insideous");
     horror.add("Sinister");
```

If you are explicilitly creating a list like this you could also do this:

Edit: Oops sorry as Obicere said ArrayList class doesnt have that constructor. Any reason you are using ArrayList rather than List?

Comment: Done! I didn't know how to until now! lol Thx again. I spent like an hour trying to figure this issue out..lol

Comment: `ArrayList<T>` doesn't have that constructor. What you're thinking of is `Arrays.asList(T...)` :)

Comment: I think I will use your suggested method because I have to add about 20 more movies, and it clean it up that's the best way ! otherwise the code would be extremely long for what your suggestion would do. Thanks again

Comment: @Obi is that for the statement? I had it a different way but I used Netbeans auto-correct \, I thought it would be better?

Comment: @Plex he meant the shortcut i posted. It wont work since you are using an arraylist data type. Any reason for not using List<string> type?

Comment: It would still work, there just isn't that specific constructor. So you could do `List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Scream", "Carrie", ...");`. This would just use `List` instead of `ArrayList`, as TheProvost has mentioned